# How do I copy an array using a reference in Perl?

Tags: perl, hash, arrays, pointers

If I do the following, it works fine:

```
print $ref->{element}->[0]->{data};
```

I would like to see how many references are in the array so that I can loop through them, but I am having a hard time doing that.

Here is the code I have tried, but it doesn't work:

```
my @array = @$ref->{element};

foreach(@array) {
    print $_->{data};
}
```

I get an "Not an ARRAY reference" error

Comment: You might find **perldoc perldsc** http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html useful.  Also, the **References Quick Reference** at Perlmonks is handy as well: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=69927

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hashes of lists are tricky that way. `@$ref->{element}` gets parsed as `(@$ref)->{element}`, dereferencing `$ref` instead of `$ref->{element}`.

Try

```
my @array = @{$ref->{element}}
```

or

```
my $size = scalar @{$ref->{element}}
```

Gory details in [perllol](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perllol).

Comment: Technically you don't need to use `scalar` to get the length, but I would probably leave it in.

Answer (score -2):

As a general aid in debugging, give [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) a look. It's invaluable for poking about in the innards of data structures.

Comment: I am using that, but that only tells me there  is an array there (which is how i know that).  Since I can access that array and print values further down, I know that isn't the issue.  What I need is to be able to loop through that array.